# How do I allow ALL ips to connect to my sql database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need all IPs to be able to connect to a MySql database. I cannot figure this out for the life of me. I don't want a range for like '192.168.0.%' I want ALL possible IPs to be able to connect to the database. I tried running

```
grant all on db.* to 'username'@'%' identified by 'password';
```

with my information filled in of course, but I get the error:

```
Error
SQL query:


grant all on db.* to 'username'@'%' identified by 'password'
MySQL said: Documentation

#1044 - Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
```

What are some commands I can use to fix this

Comment: try logging in as root

Comment: I don't have root access sadly. I am using a webhost (hosting24) that doesn't give it

Comment: Well there is your answer. Try changing to a db you have rights to.

Comment: Opening access to all ip addresses is a bad idea. Try to limit access to servers you control.

Comment: I need a C# program that I am distributing to be able to connect to the database to retrieve user info

Comment: Still a bad idea. https://www.google.com.au/search?q=mysql+open+port+hack&oq=mysql+open+port+hack&aqs=chrome..69i57.878j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 Consider building a C# restful server to talk to your mysql server.

Comment: It's **extremely risky** to directly expose your MySQL database to the internet. The best practice here is to have some kind of application layer, no matter how thin, to intermediate. This could be done with C# .Net MVC in front where you create a simple JSON over HTTPS API.

Comment: Or if you are on a typical shared hosting server that limits the languages available, you can almost always do the same type of thing - API interface - using PHP or ASP or whatever high-level scripting language they provide. It doesn't need to be C# just because the application is C#. But you definitely want a gateway of some sort between MySQL and the user-controlled devices.